# Top & Left position with Transform Rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for the JavaScript code which can arrange playing cards images as appear in the attached image, i am using CSS transform rotate with degree 7, but i tried to calculate the left and top in different ways to come up with the attached image but i was unable to do so.

[image: sample]

Comment: Got any code/jsfiddle to show for? Hard for us to help without seeing what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrange the cards, you need to transform them (using CSS transform). Firstly, for each card, you need a rotate transform around the `transform-origin` at the `right bottom` corner. So you need to calculate the rotating angle for each card (by cumulating the angle by `7deg` (or some other degree)). Secondly, you need to translate each card so that they are arranged along a path, as in your image shown, looks like this path is very close to an ellipse. So just define some ellipse via the horizontal and vertical radii (`a` and `b`), increase the rotating angle (around the center point of the ellipse) and calculate the `x` and `y` of the running point (on the ellipse path) based on the following formula (the ellipse equations in polar coordinates):

```
x = a * cos(alpha);
y = b * sin(alpha);
```

We need to calculate the `dx` and `dy` (the difference between the current `x` (`y`) and the previous `x` (`y`)) and cumulate these values to use for `translate` transform.

Here is the demo code:

**JS**:

```
var n = 13;//number of cards
var al = 7; //degree difference between 2 cards
var a = 90;//horizontal radius of the ellipse path along which the cards are arranged.
var b = 200; //vertical radius of the ellipse path along which the cards are arranged.
var step = 4;//the degree step to jump between 2 cards (along the ellipse path).

var initAlpha = (180 - al * (n - 1)) / 2;// (deg) may be negative
var beta = (180 - step * (n - 1)) / 2 - 15;//
var betaRad = beta * Math.PI / 180;
var prefixes = ["webkit","moz","ms",""];
var x = a * Math.cos(betaRad), y = b * Math.sin(betaRad);
var dx = 0, dy = 0;
function transform(elem, dx, dy, da){
  for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
    elem.style[prefixes[i]  + (prefixes[i] ? "Transform" : "transform")] = "translate(" + dx + "px," +
        dy + "px) rotate(" + da + "deg)";
  }
}
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){    
  //create new card
  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";
  document.body.appendChild(card);     
  transform(card, dx.toFixed(10), dy.toFixed(10), initAlpha);    
  beta += step;   
  initAlpha += al;
  betaRad = beta * Math.PI / 180;
  var x2 = a * Math.cos(betaRad);    
  var y2 = b * Math.sin(betaRad);
  dx += x - x2;
  dy += y - y2;    
  x = x2;
  y = y2;    
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.card {
  width:150px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:right bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin:right bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin:right bottom;
  transform-origin:right bottom;
  background:lightyellow;
  transition:background 0.3s;
}
.card:hover {
  background:orange;
}
body {
  background:black;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GL2Dg/116/)

Note the arranged cards may not look exactly to what your image shows, but it's very close. You can change the number of cards (`n`), the degree difference `al`, the horizontal radius of the ellipse path `a`, the vertical radius of the ellipse path `b`, `step`, `initAlpha`, `beta` to arrange the cards differently.

This is a **[more intuitive demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GL2Dg/120/)** in which you can set some text for the card without unexpected text direction.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort for providing elegant example, you are math genius.
Just one question here, if i want the card height to be bigger that the width, means it is showing vertically not wide, so what should i change in the code? honestly speaking i tried to understand your code to do it myself but i couldn't.

Comment: @user2155873 in fact you can just change the `width` and `height` in the CSS code (not in JS), however for easy calculation, I just set `width` bigger than `height` (which may be non-intuitive, because normally the `width` of a card should be lesser than the `height`), so you can just understand that the `width` (in CSS code) is actually the `height` of the card and vice-versa.

Comment: actually this is what i did, i tried it in JSFiddle Demo which you have sent me, i swapped the CSS width and height but it didn't give the expected shape.

Comment: @user2155873 I understand that you may want to show some text in the card, so with the current code, it's hard to show the text expectedly, I modified it to make it more intuitive. Now all the cards are vertical intially before being arranged by transforming, check this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GL2Dg/120/ BTW, if it's still not the expected result, please try posting some screenshot (like as you did in your question), I'll try to modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it, it is exactly what i want, king of the kings.

Comment: @user2155873 in fact king here may mean *very big* :)

Comment: King King, I need one more favor from you, see how you did the hover on the card which will change the BG, i am looking to do something close to that, i want to let the card z-index to be the highest when its hovered, but only when you hover a specific area on the card, something like image map but i want it to be in javascript, for example, if the card width is 100px, and height is 200px, then the area i want to cover is (left:0, top:0 -> left:20px,top:200px), means the hover will cover the whole card height, but only 10% of the card width, is it doable with the example you have provided?

Comment: @user2155873 if trying to solve it in a straight (mathematical) way, it will be a lot of code to write and buggy indeed. However we have a very elegant way by just adding some *handle* element to the `.card`, handling the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events of this *handle* and bring on top/push to back the corresponding card accordingly. Hope this demo is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/GL2Dg/124/

Comment: the thing is i am not using divs, instead i am using images so i can not create inner element as a handle.

Comment: One last request please as you did the math part, if i want the hover to let the card go up (means motion not z-index) according to the same degree it has (on the same diagonal line), then how can i calculate the new left and top?

Comment: @user2155873 theoretically, we need to translate the card along the left edge, we can modify the transform property, but it requires parsing and replacing, we can also modify the `left` and `top` with appropritate differences which can be calculated based on the rotating angle (which is used in the `rotate` transform), this edited demo should be what you need http://jsfiddle.net/GL2Dg/125/ .For the use of handle, it is the simplest (and the most effective) solution to use, as I said doing it another way is not easy, if you want to show an image, just set it as `background` for the `.card`.

Comment: BTW, if you want to add more and more functionalities to the current code, it may be more complicated with ***harder*** problems to solve (one of the problems such as holding mouse down on a card and move it around - like drag and drop), I don't really have enough time to solve all, you should try understanding all the current facts, try it yourself first and if encountering any problem, should ask in another question. Currently I've been revising all knowledge I learnt before about ***WPF*** (Windows Presentation Foundation), so don't really have much time for SO this time.

Comment: I really appreciate your support, many many thanks, it is the exact behavior i want, i didn't want to start a new thread because i knew that i need to explain everything from the beginning, any how once again thanks for your effort.