# DOM Coordinates are wrong when using CSS Transformations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to solve how to get the correct coordinates and movement of the element but find that the CSS Transformation doesn't align with the elements DOM coordinates.

I've tried to also change the properties of the element's CSS Transformation via the JS code itself.

The problem you can see in the demo is that the element doesn't reach all four corners of the `#wrap` div.

Is it also better to incorporate a `skew` or `perspective` property rather than rotations? I've just read [Top & Left position with Transform Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376672/top-left-position-with-transform-rotate) (posted as a duplicated question), but this doesn't explain how to rotation of **this** example's prespective would work?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="thing"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
$("#wrap").click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);
    document.getElementById("thing").style.left = relativeX + "px";
    document.getElementById("thing").style.top =  relativeY + "px";
    document.getElementById("thing").innerHTML = relativeX + "<br />" + relativeY;
});
});
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
}
#thing {
    background: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Live: https://jsfiddle.net/h9ad4k63/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Top & Left position with Transform Rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376672/top-left-position-with-transform-rotate)